# Reuse http connection with backend server - web fetch API

Tags: javascript, http, browser, fetch, http2

I host my website on `example.com` I host my graphQL backend on `graphql.example.com` which serves JSON over CORS. As I understand it, every request to `window.fetch('https://graphql.example.com/', ...)` requires creating a new connection. I know that the browser is able to reuse the same connection for multiple assets made to `example.com` via http2. For example, if my webpage has the `<img>`s `example.com/a.jpg` and `example.com/b.jpg` I only have to pay setting up the cost of the connection once.

Is there anyway to reuse the connection in a similar way

- (a) with `window.fetch()`
- (b) to another domain requiring CORS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was wrong about this. All fetch requests to `graphql.example.com` over CORS can reuse the same tcp connection. You can check this by [running this example](https://jsbin.com/xicarog/edit?js,console) and checking the Connection ID in chrome dev tools [image].

CORS requests will however use a different connection to non-CORS requests to the same server.

For example say you request `example.com/a.jpg` and `example.com/b.jpg` via an image tag, they will be served without CORS over one connection.

All CORS requests to `fetch('graphql.example.com')` will be served over a different connection.